# Mathematically Subtracting Values in One File from Another File

Tags: python, bash, pandas, shell, awk

I have two files, each the same size (100x12), containing numeric values, both positive and negative separated by commas.

Example output of File 1:

```
-14.99,-15.6,8.0 ->
-9.0,34.87,98.98 ->
(and so on)
```

Example output of File 2:

```
-15.99,-18.6,8.00 ->
-3.0,34.34,-98.88 ->
(and so on)
```

I have tried:

```
awk '{getline t<"file1"; print $0-t}' file2
```

However this only subtracts the first column. How can I expand this to numerically subtract file1/column1 from file2/column2?

I would be open to using pandas to perform this operation. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You won't get any benefit from pandas for a problem this small - you are better off with the solution below - faster and lower resources. (And I'm a big fan of pandas!)

Comment: Re *"to numerically subtract file1/column1 from file2/column2"*: this seems clear enough, but it might be a typo.  Please verify that the first subtraction in the given samples would be `-18.6 - -14.99` or `-18.6 + 14.99` (answer: `3.61`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the data

```
file1 = """
-14.99,-15.6,8.0 ->
-9.0,34.87,98.98 ->
"""
file2 = """
-15.99,-18.6,8.00 ->
-3.0,34.34,-98.88 ->
"""

from io import StringIO # faking file on disk
```

The pandas answer.

```
import pandas as pd
converter = {2: lambda s: float(s.split(' ')[0])}
df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(file1), header=None, converters=converter)
df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(file2), header=None, converters=converter)
(df1-df2).to_csv('pddiff12.csv', header=False, index=False)
```

Or roll it with pure python.

```
# cmt 1 -> indent under with-statement

def read_csv(file_name):
    #with open('file_name', 'rt') as f1: # uncomment when reading from disk
    f1 = StringIO(file_name) # comment out when reading from disk
    rows = [r for r in f1.readlines() if r.strip()] # cmt 1
    crunch = lambda row: [float(r) for r in row.split(',')]
    rows = [crunch(r.split(' ')[0]) for r in rows]
    return rows

data1 = read_csv(file1)
data2 = read_csv(file2)

diff = []
for row1, row2 in zip(data1, data2):
    diff.append([i-j for i, j in zip(row1, row2)])

with open('diff12.csv', 'wt') as d12:
    for row in diff:
        d12.write(', '.join((str(v) for v in row)) + '\n')
```

Pandas for sure easiest to read and get working, although it's a noticable dependency if one tends to avoid that.
In this case I think I would not.

Comment: I elected to use the Pandas solution; elegant solution with the converter - thank you!

Comment: In all honesty, started with writing the pure python thinking pandas was unnecessary bloat, however in this case pandas for sure got +1 also for me.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head - so check the syntax!

```
import numpy as np

with open("file1.txt, "r") as f1:
    with open("file2.txt, "r") as f2:
       array1 = np.asarray(f1.read().split(','))
       array2 = np.asarray(f2.read().split(','))
       result = array1 - array2
       print([x for x in result])
```

Answer (score 0):

In awk:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {                # hash file1 values to a
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        a[FNR][i]=$i
    next
}{                       # process file2, subtract values from file1 respectives
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        $i=$i-a[FNR][i]
}1' file1 file1
```

Output:

```
-1,-3,8.00 ->
6,-0.53,-98.88 ->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with unix utilities.. paste with awk

```
paste file1.txt file2.txt | 
     awk -F"[,\t]"  -v OFS="," ' { for(i=1;i<4;i++) { $i=$(i+3)-$i } print $1,$2,$3 } '
```

with the given inputs

```
$ cat halletwx1.txt
-14.99,-15.6,8.0
-9.0,34.87,98.98

$ cat halletwx2.txt
-15.99,-18.6,8.00
-3.0,34.34,-98.88

$ paste halletwx1.txt halletwx2.txt | awk -F"[,\t]"  -v OFS="," ' { for(i=1;i<4;i++) { $i=$(i+3)-$i } print $1,$2,$3 } '
-1,-3,0
6,-0.53,-197.86

$
```